# Using class from wcf service in silverlight - notifypropertychanged doesn't work

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, inotifypropertychanged

I'm having the following class defined in my wcf service

```
public class Autoturism : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _AutoturismID;
        public int AutoturismID
        { get { return _AutoturismID; } set { _AutoturismID = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("AutoturismID"); } }

        private string _NumarAutoturism;
        public string NumarAutoturism
        { get { return _NumarAutoturism; } set { _NumarAutoturism = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("NumarAutoturism"); } }

        public bool IsDirty { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            IsDirty = true;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
```

I want to use IsDirty value to check if the object needs to be saved in the database.

In a silverlight page I have the following lines:

```
AutoCurent = new Autoturism();
AutoCurent.NumarAutoturism="13424";
```

My Problem is that after the last line, I was expecting to have IsDirty= true but it is still false. I'm thinking that the Auoturism class that comes from service reference, doesn't have any more the method NotifyPropertyChanged.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: +1 for provide plenty of code and good description :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **RIA** WCF services (which I have to assume from your problem), then your Client side version of the Autoturism object will only have the properties, but not the code, from your service-side class.

Basically RIA Services creates proxy objects for the client that have the same "shape" only (but not the code).

To fully share code and data you need to have them as a .shared.cs class. Then the full source will be copied to your client project.

Comment: thank you, I was afraid of that. I'm going to search some info about shared classes